# Leer archivo json comprimido en gz en PHP

Tags: php

Buenas a todos! como estan?
les comento que tengo un problema, tengo un archivo .gz que contiene un json enorme, mi pregunta es si hay posibilidad de ingresar a este por medio de php, sin necesidad de descomprimirlo manualmente.

saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar esto:

```
$archivos = new PharData('miArchivo.tar.gz');
foreach($archivos as $archivo) { 
    $contenido = file_get_contents($archivo); // Obtengo el contenido del archivo
    $json = json_decode($contenido, true); // Parseo el JSON
    $jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( 
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST); // Genero un iterador de keys y valores

    // Imprimo los resultados
    foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
        if(is_array($val)) {
            echo "$key:\n";
        } else {
            echo "$key => $val\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta! por el momento no me funciono... pero si lo logro les aviso como!

Answer (score 0):

PHP cuenta con un módulo de funciones para trabajar con archivos .gz: [Zlib](http://php.net/manual/es/book.zlib.php). Está disponible para PHP 4, 5 y 7, y te permitirá hacer entre otras cosas:

- Comprimir y descomprimir cadenas con gzip
- Abrir y leer archivos gz
- Escribir y modificar archivoz gz

Entonces no tendrías que descomprimir manualmente el archivo gz para trabajar con el en PHP, porque puedes directamente hacerlo con PHP. Incluso, no necesitarías descomprimirlo para leer el JSON que contiene. Una manera rápida de hacerlo sería usando [`gzfile`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.gzfile.php) que lee el contenido de un archivo gz y lo pone en un array (cada fila será un elemento del array).

Esto se puede hacer así:

```
// lee el contenido del archivo gz a una variable (array)
$archivoGZ = gzfile("miArchivo.gz");

// convierte ese array a una cadena de texto
$cadenaGZ = implode("", $archivoGZ);

// conviértela a un objeto procesable por PHP
$jsonGZ = json_decode($cadenaGZ);
```

O en una sola línea:

```
$jsonGZ = json_decode( implode("", gzfile("miArchivo.gz") ) );
```

Por ejemplo, imagina que tienes un fichero JSON con el siguiente contenido:

```
[
    {
        "nombre": "Juan",
        "apellido": "Montero",
        "edad": 23
    },{
        "nombre": "Miguel",
        "apellido": "Pardo",
        "edad": 45
    },{
        "nombre": "Manuel",
        "apellido": "Castillo",
        "edad": 43
    },{
        "nombre": "Mariano",
        "apellido": "Blanco",
        "edad": 35
    }
]
```

El resultado del código anterior (si haces un `var_dump`) se vería así:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'nombre' => string 'Juan' (length=4)
      public 'apellido' => string 'Montero' (length=7)
      public 'edad' => int 23
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'nombre' => string 'Miguel' (length=6)
      public 'apellido' => string 'Pardo' (length=5)
      public 'edad' => int 45
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'nombre' => string 'Manuel' (length=6)
      public 'apellido' => string 'Castillo' (length=8)
      public 'edad' => int 43
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[4]
      public 'nombre' => string 'Mariano' (length=7)
      public 'apellido' => string 'Blanco' (length=6)
      public 'edad' => int 35
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta! por el momento no me funciono, pero voy a seguir intentando... trato de imprimir y no imprime nada...